# strange squares in term mode

Tags: terminal-emacs, term, escape

For some time I have been seeing strange squares on term-mode

Here a example with 'top' command

[image]

I am using emacs 28.2.50 with -q option.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are escape characters. `term` understand escape sequences similar to those understood by xterm (and thus similar to the VT-100/VT-220/VT-340/etc line of terminals), but `\e(B` isn’t one that I am familiar with. What is the value of `TERM` in that shell?

Comment: TERM was xterm-256color, with TERM=eterm-color, the problem go away, Thanks !